# How to save image to user folder in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to save uploaded images to separate folders. So for example user 4 photos should be stored in /media/images/4/

Here is the function and model and views that I came up with:

Model:

```
def get_uplaod_file_name(user,filename):
    return 'photos/%s/%s_%s' %  str(user.id),  (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)



class UserPic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    picfile = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to= get_uplaod_file_name, sizes=((200,200),(1200,1200)))
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200 , blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_pirate', None, {'user': self.account.user})    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.picfile.name)
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    thisuser =User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
    # Load pics of this user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        picform = PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if picform.is_valid():
            newpic = UserPic(picfile = request.FILES['picfile'])
            newpic = picform.save(commit=False)
            newpic.user_id = request.user.id
            newpic.save()
            message = "file %s is uploaded" % newpic

    else:
        picform = PicForm() # A empty, unbound form

    args= {}
    args['picform'] = picform

    return render_to_response('userpics/upload.html',args,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, after many tweaks of `get_uplaod_file_name` it still does not work. I get errors like:

```
TypeError at /pics/upload/
not enough arguments for format string
```

Appreciate your help to resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass a tuple to the string formatting operator:

```
def get_uplaod_file_name(userpic, filename):
    return u'photos/%s/%s_%s' % (str(userpic.user.id),
                                 str(time()).replace('.', '_'),
                                 filename)
```

Note the first and last round brackets.

Also note the unicode prefix `u'` which is mandatory in case if user will upload a file with non-ascii symbols in the name.

Comment: Using the tuple resolve the error, but the images are now saved in `photos/None/` instead of, say, `photos/4/` (where 4 is user.id)

Comment: The instance passed to the upload function is the `UserPic`, not the `User`.  So change the signature of the function and replace `user.id` with the `userpic.user.id`.  See the updated version in my answer.